# Subsetting data frame returns empty data frame

Tags: r

I know it shows that this question has been already been asked/answered here: [(R) [] / subset() returns an empty data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787758/r-subset-returns-an-empty-data-frame) but it didn't have the solution I was looking for. (My columns do not have padded white space)

So here is my original data

```
head(d)
County    ID     event1       event2         row1           row2  
Rogers    1      Hearing      Application    Plea           Trial
Rogers    2      Arrest       Hearing        Application    Plea
Rogers    3      Arrest       Hearing        Plea           Disposal
```

I needed the events and rows columns to all exist in one row.

```
events <- d %>%
  select(County, ID, contains("event"), contains("row")) %>%
  gather(m, event, contains("event")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(event)) %>%
  select(-m)

 head(events)
 County     ID     event        row1         row2
 Rogers     1      Hearing      Plea         Trial
 Rogers     1      Application  Plea         Trial
 Rogers     2      Arrest       Application  Plea
 Rogers     2      Hearing      Application  Plea
```

I still needed the row columns as events.

```
events2 <- events %>%
  select(County, ID, event, contains("row")) %>%
  gather(m, event, contains("row")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(event)) %>%
  select(-m)
```

I hoped it would look like this.

```
head(events2)
County      ID        event
Rogers      1         Hearing
Rogers      1         Application
Rogers      1         Plea
Rogers      1         Trial
```

But instead it returned an empty data frame with 0 observations.

```
events2
NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please list package dependencies?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue i.e I am getting an output

Comment: @akrun I am getting a data frame however it is not named "events2" nor does it appear when I type `events2` in the script

Comment: I am getting `events %>% select(County, ID, event, contains("row")) %>% gather(m, event, contains('row')) %>% select(-m) %>% head#
  County ID       event
1 Rogers  1        Plea
2 Rogers  2 Application`

Comment: Do you need both events as you have AND `events2`? Or do you only want `events2`?

Comment: Also can't reproduce it. I loaded `tidyverse`. Not sure what libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to those mentioning in the comments, I also cannot reproduce your problem even just copy/pasting your code. That is, I get the expected output. But I do have a solution that may help.

Perhaps you can mitigate the problem by doing 1 round of piping and instead of using `contains()` using the regular expression version, `matches()` to match '`row'` OR `'event'`, which effectively matches column heads with 'row' AND 'event'. This eliminates having to run the piping sequence twice where mistakes can be made with the copy-paste-change approach (I know I make them all the time).

```r
events <- d %>% 
  select(County,ID,matches('event|row')) %>% 
  gather(m,event,matches('row|event[0-9]+')) %>% 
  select(-m) %>%
  filter(!is.na(event))
```

Briefly, the call to `matches()` in the `gather()` function says: *Match 'row' or match 'event' when it is followed by at least one number between 0 and 9*. See this neat graphic for more info: [Regular Expressions in R](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf).

I had to sort the data.frame after, but then I get:

```
>head(events)
  County ID       event
  Rogers  1     Hearing
  Rogers  1 Application
  Rogers  1        Plea
  Rogers  1       Trial
  Rogers  2      Arrest
  Rogers  2     Hearing
```

I am using tidyverse v1.2.1. Hope that helps!